# Redirections and Return Codes

Tags: shell, io-redirection, exit-status

So I have a program that may or may not segfault (*./segf*) that also writes other data to stderr. When the program segfaults, its return code is 139 (i.e. `echo $?` will print `139`).

I would like to redirect stderr to `/dev/null` so as to avoid printing it, however doing so (`./segf 2>1`) causes the return code to be set to 1. Now it's impossible to differentiate whether the program is truly segfaulting or just returning an error.

Is it possible to pipe stderr's other errors while still being able to check that the return code would be 139?

`./segf >/dev/null; echo $?` results in 139

`./segf >/dev/null 2>1; echo $?` results in 1

`bash -c './segf'` results in 139

`bash -c './segf' 2>1` results in 1

Comment: `./segf >/dev/null 2>1` will redirect the stderr to a _file_ called `1`. Is that really what you ran?

Comment: Doing `2>1` you write the standard error to the file  with name "1". The `2>&1` should be used. [whats difference between 2>1 > /dev/null and 2>&1 >/dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9390124/2913477)

Comment: Why does having stderr go to /dev/null cause the program not to segfault? Based on your description it appears that the program is going out of its way to work differently depending on where stderr is going to. In that case by definition the answer to your question is `no`, if stderr is redirected then you don't get a segfault, so the return code doesn't indicate you did.

Comment: @terdon Yes, 2>1 goes to a file called 1, however changing it to 2>&1 doesn't affect the main issue with return code being altered due to redirection.

Comment: @jbal where is `&1` being sent to when you do that? Are you trying to write to a file you don't have access to? What does `./segf 2>&1; echo $?` return?

Comment: @terdon Nope, no permission issues. If I do 2>1, the file is created and written to. The return code is then just 1.

Comment: @jbal are you _sure_ it is written to? A return of `1` [usually means "permission denied"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326811/22222). And what happens when you run `./segf 2>/dev/null; echo $?`?

Comment: @icarus that's probably it. the segv causing bug may even be in the error-coloring code turned on only when the stderr is a tty  -- such a thing actually happened in gcc or clang, but I'm not able to find a reference.

Comment: @terdon No, an exit status  of 1 means just failure. The exit status has **no relationship whatsoever** to the errno values you link to, and it's only defined for the values 0 = success, anything else = failure. An exit status > 128 in the shell *may* be caused by a process being killed by signal `$? - 128` but it's easily fakeable by eg. an `exit 139`.

Comment: @mosvy if the error is returned by the program, it can be arbitrary, yes. But if the error is caused by the redirection (as the question had originally suggested), then it would be output by the shell would most likely mean permission denied. Note that the OP is using `$?` to check the error, that's the shell. Also note that I said _usually_ means. Many tools do actually use those conventions, so I don't know why you feel there's **no relationship whatsoever** (nor why you felt you needed to put that in bold).

Comment: @terdon not at all; the shell could also return 1 for syntax errors and a lot of other conditions (including but not limited to redirections failing because of other causes than "permission denied"). And if the shell would've failed to redirect the stderr of the command, it would've also printed an error message to the *non-redirected* stderr. I put that in bold because this idea that errno == exit status is an annoying urban legend, only perpertuated through forums like this (there's really nothing in the docs or source code of real programs to suggest that).

Comment: @mosvy the shell returns `2` for syntax errors, but my point was about the shell and how attempting to write to a file you don't have access to does indeed return `1` and could have explained this. And I know it would have printed a message, that's why I show that message in my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try `echo ${y$ck}` in `bash`, `zsh`, etc. and check the `$?` afterwards.

Comment: @mosvy true, thanks. I was thinking of things like `for i; echo; done`, that give  syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

None of the things you tried should affect the exit status. You can test with this very simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo out
echo err >&2
exit 139
```

Now execute it with the various redirects:

```
$ foo.sh; echo $?
out
err
139

#redirect stdout to /dev/null and stderr to a file called '1'
$ foo.sh >/dev/null 2>1; echo $?
139

## Redirect stderr to /dev/null
$ foo.sh 2>/dev/null; echo $? 
out
139
```

The way to redirect a command's stderr is just `command 2>/dev/null`, but that should never affect the command's exit status, unless the redirection fails. This is actually what probably happened in your case. If you don't have write permissions in the directory where you are and you tried to run `./segf >/dev/null 2>1` (instead of `./segf >/dev/null 2>&1`), that would have attempted to create a *file* called `1` to redirect stderr to. If the file can't be created, you would get an exit status of `1`:

```
$ foo.sh 2>1; echo $? 
bash: 1: Permission denied
1
```

Comment: Note that segfaulting (or, more generally, being killed by a signal) is different from exiting with a return code >128. Can you still reproduce this with `kill -SEGV $$` or similar? (Sorry, typing from phone, can't check myself.) I'm also skeptical of the claim, just pointing out your reproducer might not be close enough to the OP's.

Comment: @filbranden yes, that's a fair point, but no matter how it is killed, redirection should never affect the exit status. And I can't test with `kill -SEGV $$` since if file `1` isn't writeable, the script will exit immediately as soon as it attempts to write to stderr. The issue is almost certainly that the OP was trying to write to file that wasn't writeable, so the shell was killing the process long before the segfault was ever reached.