# building Debian package from Buster fails on Bookworm

Tags: debian, compiling, make, dpkg, cmake

I need to use older version of `linphone` on Debian 12.

The version in bookworm is `4.4.10-3`, and I actually need `3.12.0`, which is available in Buster.

On my bookworm build machine, I changed the sources, and downloaded `linphone-3.12.0` sources from buster. Then I switched sources back to bookworm, and installed any necessary dependencies.

#### Update with more details

I made some progress, and now I get much further in the compilation process. However, it fails eventually:

```
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
[ 66%] Built target linphone-static
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:159: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
dh_auto_build: error: cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && make -j4 "INSTALL=install --strip-program=true" VERBOSE=1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [debian/rules:15: binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
```

The full build output [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQMQ3_EA) and debian/rules [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQFuItFg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the standard error codes in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326766/what-are-the-standard-error-codes-in-linux)

Comment: What kind of compiler are you using?  I would recommend using exactly the same version as in Buster.

Comment: @tukan
 - I am using the build tool chain from bookworm. Shouldn't the compiler be backward compatible ?

Comment: @400theCat It should be backward compatible, but it is never 100%.

Comment: `gcc` is backward compatible (within reason) but the other build tools may not be. Try running it in a container or virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build fails because of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py", line 764, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py", line 760, in main
    genwrapper.render_all()
  File "/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py", line 700, in render_all
    self.render(header, self.includedir + '/enums.hh')
  File "/mnt/src/deb/LINPHONE/linphone-3.12.0/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py", line 716, in render
    with open(tmppath, mode='rU') as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU'
```

Python 3 no longer has a “U” mode for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). To fix this, add `debian/patches/genwrapper.patch` containing

```
Index: linphone-3.12.0/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py
===================================================================
--- linphone-3.12.0.orig/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py
+++ linphone-3.12.0/wrappers/cpp/genwrapper.py
@@ -713,7 +713,7 @@ class GenWrapper(object):
                content = ''
                with open(tmppath, mode='w') as f:
                        f.write(self.renderer.render(item))
-               with open(tmppath, mode='rU') as f:
+               with open(tmppath, mode='r') as f:
                        content = f.read()
                with open(path, mode='w') as f:
                        f.write(content)
```

and add it to `debian/patches/series`:

```
$ echo genwrapper.patch >> debian/patches/series
```

Comment: thank you, but it fails with another error: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQCSbBEg

Comment: your answer solved one set of errors, but there are more. Do you know how to successfully compile linphone 3.12.0 on Debian 12 ? I will now award the bounty, since it is expiring. But the problem is not solved yet. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I’ve been meaning to revisit this. There’s a problem with the link order; IIRC `ld` became stricter sometime between Buster and Bullseye. Could you share how you worked around the `FindORTP` build error?