# Return "continue" from function called from loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, control-flow

I'm currently refactoring a script which has slowly grown beyond control. I'm trying to spin off repetition into functions. However, I have a repeated test being called from a loop, and want it to return `continue`.

Shellcheck says

```
SC2104: In functions, use `return` instead of `continue`.
```

And the shellcheck wiki says don't do it. But is there a way?

Below is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh

AFunction () {
    if [[ "${RED}" -lt 3 ]]; then
        echo "cont"
        continue
    else
        echo "nope"
    fi
}

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    RED=${i}
    AFunction
    echo ${i}
done
```

This is the output:

```
cont
1
cont
2
nope
3
nope
4
nope
5
```

But I would expect

```
cont
cont
nope
3
nope
4
nope
5
```

---

Thanks everyone for the answers so far. I'm close but now have a spin off question. Hopefully that's ok?

If I use a combination of @sudodus answer and @alecxs tips. Do I need to then always "return" a 0 at the end of the function? Seems like good practice now, but is it implied if I don't explicitly do it?

```
#!/bin/sh

AFunction () {
    ##Script doing loads of other stuff
    if [[ "${RED}" -lt 3 ]]; then
        echo "cont"
        ## This only happening because something has gone wrong
        return 1
    else
        echo "nope"
    fi
    ##Script doing loads of more stuff
}

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    RED=${i}
    AFunction || continue
    echo ${i}
done
```

Comment: Exactly how are you running this? If I run the contents of the function in bash (like you tagged), it throws 'continue: only meaningful in a ... loop'. If I run it in sh (like your shebang) it throws 'sh: 1: [[: not found'. I think your /bin/sh is a link to ksh.

Comment: Hi @alecxs, so the problem is I want to return the command to continue from the function to be used in the loop.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, I would not be surprised if the shell behaves a bit odd, it's ancient. It needs to run on SUSE 11.0. Patching these old boxes up to 11.4 is another task.

Comment: See https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=842 and https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1058 for what POSIX has to say about that.

Comment: yes, to be safe usually return 0 is placed at end of function. in other cases it might useful to return exit code from child process via variable, that way you can check the success of other commands (like rsync) but in your case just 0 and 1 is sufficient https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'return` with a parameter for example like the following,

```
#!/bin/bash

AFunction () {
    if [[ "${RED}" -lt 3 ]]; then
        echo "cont"
        return 1
    else
        echo "nope"
        return 0
    fi
}

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    RED=${i}
    if AFunction
    then
    echo ${i}
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi @sudodus, this is a lot cleaner than what the shellcheck wiki says. I'll just test it now and see if it works in the main script.

Comment: Thanks @alecxs, I think that's what I need. @sudodus If you just do `AFunction || continue` will that work?

Comment: @Stripy42, Please explain why you want to use `continue`. What is the action that you need in your 'big script'?

Comment: @sudodus `continue` is used in loops to break the current iteration without processing code (like `break` does end the entire loop)

Comment: Hi @sudodus, I've just moded the question I hope that helps a bit. The big function is a complex file preparation and transfer system. It gets info from one system ready for another, but the source system is prone to sending out corrupt data. The function is checking a few files. And either rsync'ing them or throwing a "continue" for the overall script to skip to the next set of files.

Comment: @Stripy42, alecxs is right about the usage of `continue`. My question was more about why you prefer it to the `ìf` statement. What you want it is perform some action depending of some condition, and to continue the loop. If the function might break the loop, I think it would make a difference. Use the syntax that works best and/or gives the cleanest syntax. -- What kind of 'continue' is it? How is it sent from the function in the 'big script'? And what is sent otherwise (nothing or something else)?

Comment: Hi, I'm now using the fix you've provided (thanks!) to replace a lot of repetitive tasks I've taken out of what was a single loop into functions. So I'll likely use both option, the  short && + || and the IF ELSE FI option, depending on what the functions do.

Comment: Congratulations :-) I'm glad that I could help with one piece to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

AFunction () {
    [ "${RED}" -lt 3 ]
}

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    RED=${i}
    if AFunction
    then
      echo "cont"
    else
      echo "nope"
      echo ${i}
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be good if the function was that simple. Unfortunately, the example is extremely pared down.

Comment: If the function is in reality a procedure (ie. you don't need to return a value), end it with true or false to indicate if the loop should continue or not.

Comment: Hi @gerard-h-pille, Could you explain what the difference between a function and procedure is in bash?

Comment: As in most programming languages that I know, a function returns something, a procedure doesn't.  In a shell, they would all be functions, since they at least return the result code of the last executed statement.