# cronjob creates tar file but unable to upload it

Tags: bash, cron, tar

I am trying to schedule a backup script using a combination of `cronjob`, '`tar`, and upload to an HPSS using htar utilities. I have set absolute paths in the crontab for all commands needed in the script, but, the script still fails. A sample of the error I'm getting is below. The exit code I get from the script is 72, which is [critical OS file missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254747/139955).
I know the file exists in the specified directory.

If I run the script from the terminal (without cronjob), it works just fine.

How can I make the script work with a cronjob?

The crontab file looks like this:

```
PATH=/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/user/backup/script.sh
```

The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
Beginning backup of the server
Beginning htar...
INFO: I/O error occurred, and error -2 trying to stat file upload.tar
INFO: Retrying after I/O error at archive file offset 0
INFO: I/O error occurred, and error -2 trying to stat file upload.tar
INFO: Retrying after I/O error at archive file offset 0
INFO: I/O error occurred, and error -2 trying to stat file upload.tar
INFO: Retrying after I/O error at archive file offset 0
INFO: I/O error occurred, and error -2 trying to stat file upload.tar
INFO: Retrying after I/O error at archive file offset 0
72
```

A snippet of the script I am running looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
log=path_to_log_file
home_source=path_to_home
backup_source=path_to_backup

echo "Beginning backup of server" >> $log
sudo /usr/bin/tar -cf $backup_source/home.tar.gz $home_source

echo "Beginning htar..." >> $log
/usr/local/bin/htar -cvf "upload.tar" $backup_source/'home.tar.gz' >> $log

RETVAL=$?

echo $RETVAL >> $log
```

Comment: You're missing the absolute path for `upload.tar`.

Comment: I believe `upload.tar` is just to upload that file to the default directory on the HPSS server.

Comment: The same error still exists.

Comment: Does the user have permission to write `upload.tar` in the working directory that cron gives the script? If you need to write to a _specific_ directory, either use an absolute pathname for the archive file, or `cd` to a known location in the script.  If this tries to store the archive on some other server (I've never seen `htar` before), then ask the admin of that server whether you have permission to store data there or whether the disk is full.

Comment: According to what seems to be the [`htar` manual](https://hpc.llnl.gov/manuals/ezstorage/htar-options), you should be able to get more debug output with `-d N` (where `N` is some digit between 1 and 5).